# Umbraco 7: Reference / set path to views in separate folders

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I've put all my Views in their own folders in Visual Studio and now the content is not rendering anymore. From where do I have to set the path for them to render?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the convention is that Umbraco templates live in the ~/View folder. If they live anywhere else you loose the tooling support in the backoffice (and confuse any other Umbraco devs who pick up the project!).

However, provided the folder names match the names of the document types, you could create a controller for each of your document types (i.e. hijack the routing). I'm sure this would allow Umbraco to check in the subfolders.

Comment: it does certainly for the surfacecontroller under /View/MyController/.  Not sure for the RenderMvcController

Comment: so what is the solution for multi site implementation, lets say if have to do 10 sites in the same Umbraco project?

Comment: Phew, well ... you could override the routing described here: http://shazwazza.com/post/Custom-MVC-routing-in-Umbraco. However, you should first consider a more over-arching approach like the Hybrid Framework. Implement your own default controller to do a lot of the heavy lifting. Personally, if it unavoidable, I'd look at prefixing your controllers per site, inheriting from base controllers where functionality needs to be duplicated across sites.

Comment: To be honest though, I question the sense in hosting 10 sites in a single Umbraco instance. If the sites are all "themed" versions of the same site, then you can get away with a smaller set of controllers but a larger number of templates which are easier to organise. If they aren't, you should first question why you are hosting 10 sites in a single Umbraco instance.

Comment: What I am trying to do and understand is how to create and manage ~10 sites from a single backend. Some of them share similar functionality and layouts, others don't. Do I need a single Umbraco instance to achieve this? How can I organize my MVC files while they will start to pile up from all the different sites? Or can I make a single backend login that redirects to a site backend based on credentials? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well this is a different question and one that maybe more suited to the Umbraco forum. But what I would say is that the _only_ time I would host multiple sites in a single Umbraco instance is when they shared specific content/media. I would ask yourself why you are avoiding using multiple instances? If it is so that an editor/administrator has a single backoffice then you're making a rod for you own back.

Comment: ok, posted to Umbraco forum http://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/56847-Manage-~10-sites-from-a-single-Back-End

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing a multisite with single core Umbraco 7.  Here's how I'm handling that at the moment:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Core.Logging;

namespace MyApp.UmbracoExtensions.Shared.Events
{
    public class RegisterCustomViewEngine : ApplicationEventHandler
    {
        protected override void ApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());

            base.ApplicationStarting(umbracoApplication, applicationContext);
        }
    }

    public class CustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        private static string[] NewViewFormats = new[] {
            "~/Views/SomeFolder/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/AnotherFolder/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Wiki/{0}.cshtml"
        };

        public CustomViewEngine()
        {
            base.ViewLocationFormats = base.ViewLocationFormats.Union(NewViewFormats).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```